# JavaScript - OffFocus event?

Tags: javascript, html, focus, dom-events

What I want to do is display an input field with the text color `black`.

Then when the person clicks inside the input field (`onfocus`) I want to change the text color to `red`.

Then, when the person click outside of the input field (no longer focus), I want to change the text color back to `black`.

I know how to handle the JavaScript `onfocus` event using the following:

```
<input ctype="text" onfocus="this.style.color='red';" />
```

*But how do I handle the "off focus" to change the text color back to black?*

Answer (score 26, accepted):

try using [onblur](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onblur.asp), it is called when an element loses focus.

Comment: it is a little odd, but it does match up with the other events (onclick, onkeyup, onchange, etc.)

Comment: @PlezHelp: you should not read "onfocus" as "when 'focus' becomes 'on'", but as "when the 'focus' event happens, do ..". So 'onblur' becomes "when the blur event happens, do.." (and then you need to know that "blur" is the opposite of "focus")

Answer (score 3):

Use the [`onBlur`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onblur) event:

```
<input ctype="text" onfocus="this.style.color='red';" onblur="this.style.color='black';"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

rather than fire some JS on the event, you can use css selectors.

`#someInput:focus { color: red; } #someInput { color: black; }`

will do the same thing without javascript.