# Remove focus from element in IE11

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, tooltip, jquery-ui-dialog, jquery-tooltip

I have the following image: [image: tooltip]

The problem is that because of that focus, the jquery UI tolltip will not close after I close a modal(that was generated by that link with the tooltip)

After I close the jquery UI dialog modal, the tooltip gets recreated.

If I hit TAB, the selection will move to the next one and the tolltip apeears on the next one.

Here is what I have tried:

```
$('.btnDelete').tooltip().click(function ()
{
    $(this).blur();
    $(this).tooltip("close");
});
```

I belieive that if I remove the focus, I will solve my problem.

Comment: Can you set up an example to play with?

Comment: what if you set focus to another element?

Comment: @empiric, will that help ? It's only a problem on IE

Comment: @Veverke, does not help apparently

Comment: @empiric, here is the fiddle, but it is not a completely working solutilon


https://jsfiddle.net/Raziel369/nynwkbmq/

Answer (score 1):

I have found the solution: `tabindex = -1`

```
<a tabindex="-1" title="Sterge" class="btnDelete" onclick="OpenDialog(this, true); return false;" href=".../Delete/43">Delete</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of calling `blur()` give the focus to another element which will inherently remove the focus from previous element. Try this:

```
$('.btnDelete').tooltip().click(function () {
    $(this).tooltip("close");
    $(document).focus(); // document is an example, the selector can be made more specific
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Rory's suggestion if that doesn't work then perhaps try the onBlur() function like suggested in this [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1135708/javascript-offfocus-event)

Comment: <a class="btnDelete" href=.../Delete/46" onblur="$(this).tooltip('close');" onclick="OpenDialog(this, true); return false;" title="Delete">Delete</a>
  does not help unfortunately